# Using $gt Operator in MongoDB View Aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation

I have an aggregation pipeline in my MongoDB backend that goes through a multitude of steps, the last of which is a `$project` that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1.0,
  "visit": {
    "_id": 1.0,
    "service": 1.0,
    "dateOfVisit": 1.0,
    "type": 1.0
  },
  "customer": {
    "_id": 1.0,
    "name": 1.0
  },
  "staffPerson": {
    "_id": 1.0,
    "name": 1.0
  },
  "balance": 1.0,
  "updatedAt": 1.0
}
```

What I'm now trying to do is limit this to records where "balance" is > 0. In other words, I only want to return records where there is a balance due. I tried doing this:

```
{
  "_id": 1.0,
  "visit": {
    "_id": 1.0,
    "service": 1.0,
    "dateOfVisit": 1.0,
    "type": 1.0
  },
  "customer": {
    "_id": 1.0,
    "name": 1.0
  },
  "staffPerson": {
    "_id": 1.0,
    "name": 1.0
  },
  "balance": { $gt : 0 },
  "updatedAt": 1.0
}
```

But that gives me this error message:

> Expression $gt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.

So then I tried this:

```
    {
      "_id": 1.0,
      "visit": {
        "_id": 1.0,
        "service": 1.0,
        "dateOfVisit": 1.0,
        "type": 1.0
      },
      "customer": {
        "_id": 1.0,
        "name": 1.0
      },
      "staffPerson": {
        "_id": 1.0,
        "name": 1.0
      },
      "balance": { $gt : 0, 1.0 },
      "updatedAt": 1.0
    }
```

But that gets me another error, about field names needing to be quotes. So it looks like my syntax is incorrect here.

I also tried passing in an array of two values:

```
{ $gt: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }
```

But this returns a boolean, rather than the actual value.

How can I use `$gt` here, to return only records where "balance" is greater than zero?

Comment: Are you trying to do the `$gt` in the `$project` step? or in a previous step?

Comment: In the $project step. Do I need to do that in a different step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 different `$gt` usages:

- [$gt (comparison query operator)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#gt)
- [$gt (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/#gt-aggregation)

In the `$project` context, you are using the **aggregation operator**.  The aggregation operator will return `true`/`false` and accepts an Array of 2 parameters to operate with.  An example usage would be:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            _id:1,
            balance: {
                $gt: ["balance", 0]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

That would spit out:

```
{_id: "SOME_ID_0", balance: true}
{_id: "SOME_ID_1", balance: false}
{_id: "SOME_ID_2", balance: false}
```

---

You don't want that.  You actually want items with balance less than `0` to be filtered.  To do that, you should include a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#match-aggregation) stage which can actually filter out documents.

`$match` takes a [`query`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#query-documents) object as an argument.  Which means you can use the `$gt` **query operator**.

Considering that, your example would looks something like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{ // Filter documents that don't have balance > 0
            balance: {
                $gt: 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{ // Project documents in this format
            _id: 1,
            balance: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

---

Also see this answer: [mongodb aggregation filter for records with a field greater than or equal to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24269347/691711).

Comment: I tried something like this too. But it gives me a boolean "true" or "false" rather than the actual amount.

Comment: @Muirik I think this may be the correct way to do it.  Use `$match` and then `$project`.